# How to create a JavaScriptObject by hand in GWT?

Tags: gwt

how could i create an JavaScriptObject by hand when i have this class

```
public class Person extends JavaScriptObject{
    protected Person(){}

    public final native String FirstName()/*-{
        return this.firstName;
    }-*/; 

    public final native String LastName()/*-{
        return this.lastName;
    }-*/;
 }
```

i am asking because i have an array of this JavaScriptObject Peron

```
public JsArray<Person> persons = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
```

and i would like to full this array with some of these Person objects

```
Peson a = new Person();
a.setfirstName(textField1.getText());
a.setLastName(textField2.getText());
persons.push(a)
```

but i doesnt know how to create such an object by hand.
The values of firstName and lastName i would take from an UI component like an textField.
Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do this?

```
Person a = (Person)JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i have two questions:                                  1) is there a difference between your and this version ->         Person a = Person.createObject()cast();                                         2) how could i pass values to the person object? should i create setter methods? but in classes which extends JavaScriptObjects are no variables allowed. so how could i pass the values lastName and firstName to the object?

Comment: There is no difference between two createObject methods, since it is a static method on JavascriptObject class.

Comment: For the 2nd question, You extend JavascriptObject to access native JSON objects. The setters would be native calls that assigns the value to native Javascript variables. I think for this reason, they have put a rule that member variables are not allowed in overlay types. Please read https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay for more details.

Comment: class Person extends JavaScriptObject{
protected Person(){}
public final native String FirstName()/*-{
return this.firstName;
}-*/; 
public final native String LastName()/*-{
return this.lastName;
}-*/;
public final native String setFirstName(String fName)/*-{
this.firstName = fName;
}-*/; 
public final native String setLastName(String lName)/*-{
this.lastName = lName;
}-*/;
}
Person a = (Person)JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
a.setFirstName("Peter");
a.setLastName("Pan");
public JsArray<Person> persons = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
persons.push(a);
thx krishnakumarp